# what does quotechar mean in mysql while importing data?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Someone sent me a `xlsx` excel file and I opened it with excel and saved as csv with utf8 encoding.

---

I use mysql workbench import wizard to **import an excel-made utf8 csv** file to a database table. But the imported result missed some data (less than it should have).

And I think it has something to do with the **quotechar**.

By default the **quotechar** is double quote but I have some data like this (mixing single quote and double quote):

- 8'10" foo bar
- 4" x 6" foo foo bar

I've try to omit the value but it can't (see the error from the pic).

So here I want to figure out:

1. What does **quotechar** mean here? How does it work? Why does it matter? Can't it just import everything from the csv file?
2. How can I import the data correctly while my data mixes single quote and double quote (later I need to retrieve them and use as search keywords, so it'd be better to keep the original form)?

[image]

my data looks like this in excel: 
[image]

Comment: Ok, so you have values separated by commas. What if you have commas in the data? Well a common approach is to wrap all the text in double quotes (I think Excel export does this by default). This way, one can distinguish between the commas (between the quotes) and the commas that delineate the columns. Now what happens when you have double quotes in the data? You must use a different character to enclose your strings (or columns). One that does not exist in the data.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472683/what-does-quotechar-mean-in-mysql-while-importing-data and should be closed.

Comment: @JacobH thanks, your comment solved one of my confusion. I opened the csv file in Sublime Text and did some data with comma are wrapped in double quotes. And now I understand why.

Comment: @MikeLischke there's a useful comment here and I would like to keep the question. Do I disobey any rules if I ask a question at both sites? Because I think there might be different views (maybe some specialists visit this site more often, sort of thing).

Comment: Answering questions is work, believe me. And that requires to go to the individual questions, reading them, understand them and see if one can come up with a good answer. Doing that multiple times for the same question is just a waste of time and hence annoying for most people. It also leads to fragmentation (different, maybe valid, points on different question incarnations).

Comment: @MikeLischke Ok, i would follow your advice and stop posting same question on different sub-sites.

Comment: Search the web for `workbench quotechar`.